# TabBarController called by a TableViewCell in another TabBarController

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I was wondering if it is possible to have the following:

One TabBarController with two buttons containing a UITableView in each one. 
Then, if one of the TableView cells is clicked, I would like to push to a new TabBarController with a different set of 4 buttons containing other table views.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

The first thing I tried was set up the first TabBarController with the UITableView under each button. But when I added the second TabBarController to be triggered from a clicked tableview cell, what I got was the first Tab which contains the 2 buttons, and on top of that, the second tab containing the 4 buttons.

I would like the second TabBarController to replace and leave behind the first one.

I hope I explained myself well enough, thank you for your time.

Comment: maybe you could show the code you have now - or describe how your storyboard items are linked.

Comment: @HeWas I have not really written any code. The way I linked the items in the storyboard is: Inserted a TabBarController (with two views/buttons), in each of those views I have a UITableView. From a cell of those tableviews I created a segue (push) to a new TabBarController which contains 4 items/buttons. And that's pretty much it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your push segue to a modal segue.

To go back you are going to need to implement a return button in your destination viewController:

```
- (IBAction) dismiss:(id)sender
{
    [[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

(note that you must do this in code - you cannot draw a segue line to go back)

At the moment you must have a navigation controller involved in your push segue. When you change to a modal segue you can remove the navController, it won't play a part in the navigation.

Comment: Thanks!!! But now I have another question... I took out the Navigation Controller and I added just a Navigation Bar for each item in the TabBarController via the Attributes Inspector... Do I have to do anything else in order for that Navigation Bar to show up when I build the project? So far, it isn't showing.